# Trivialize triangle inequality with linear algebra?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

I managed to prove the triangle inequality with linear algebra however I feel like there is some algebraic identity that trivializes this inequality.

Let $a=[a_1, a_2, ... a_n],b=[b_1, b_2, ... b_n]\ \epsilon\ \mathbb{R}^n$, then we have $$\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2...a_n^2}+\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2...a_n^2}\geq \sqrt{(a_1+b_1)^2+(a_2+b_2)^2...(a_n+b_n)^2}$$.

My solution is to simply square both sides and the rest can be simplified by cancellation and CS inequality. However, it looks like there is an identity (maybe Holder's?) that directly trivializes this problem. Is this true?

Comment: This is one of the defining features of the vector [Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition) and hence is trivially true.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the triangle inequality. Vector spaces don't have the ability to multiply vectors by themselves, clearly $\mathbb R^n$ has an additional structure that allows you to do that. What you've shown is that the Euclidean metric is, in fact, a metric. You've shown that it serves as a norm.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cauchy-Schwarz,
\begin{align}
\|a+b\|^2&=(a+b)^T(a+b)=a^Ta+b^Tb+2b^Ta\\[0.2cm]
&\leq a^Ta+b^Tb+2\|a\|\,\|b\|\\[0.2cm]
&=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2+2\|a\|\,\|b\|=(\|a\|+\|b\|)^2.
\end{align}
Taking square roots (of positive numbers), you get 
$$
\|a+b\|\leq\|a\|+\|b\|. 
$$